# jQuery if url matches

Tags: jquery

I want to reach something like this:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/")){
 ... then to this
}
```

but it still runs when url looks like this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/`

Comment: Are you asking for a regex to validate urls?

Comment: Your IF condition is not valid anyway... you should do: if(window.location.href.indexOf("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/") > -1){
 ... then to this
}

Comment: You'll want to investigate the possible return values of indexOf()

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
if(window.location.href === "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/"){
    ... then to this
}
```

Comment: Should not we use `===` for comparison?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan you are right. When it comes to JavaScript, its a bad practice to depend on ==. Either store the value (=), or check for strict equivalence (===). Good catch.